# Facebook comment_plugin_count can be wrong

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

If you navigate to https://techcrunch.com/2018/01/13/google-assistant-had-a-good-ces/, you can see at least three "Facebook Comments Plugin" comments after the article.

But if you query Facebook's graph API, as per the graph explorer, with a `GET -> v2.11 / ?id=https%3A%2F%2Ftechcrunch.com%2F2018%2F01%2F13%2Fgoogle-assistant-had-a-good-ces&fields=engagement`, you'll see an incorrect field for comment_plugin_count, 0, but it should have been what you see at TechCrunch's Facebook Comments Plugin (currently 3).

Or put another way: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/?fields=engagement&format=json&id=https%3A%2F%2Ftechcrunch.com%2F2018%2F01%2F13%2Fgoogle-assistant-had-a-good-ces&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&appsecret_proof=MY_SECRET`

returns `{ ... "comment_plugin_count": 0 ... }`

Why doesn't that query return the expected "comment_plugin_count"?

Comment: Why are you querying comments on Techcrunch?

Comment: Eight years ago, I made a feed that surfaced TechCrunch articles that had more comments and shares than the others. Back then, WordPress comments, Disqus comments and the slash:comments tags all worked. But now that they're using FaceBook Comments Plugin, I apparently can't use the comment count as a signal anymore. http://david.dlma.com/blog/my-techcrunch-feed-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "comment_plugin_count" is generated differently than the other engagement fields. While the other fields will be correct regardless of whether the URL has a terminating slash, the comment_plugin_count will only be correct if you specify the expected URL. In this case, the expected URL should have a terminating slash. (Specified by "%2F".)

I should have been using `id=https%3A%2F%2Ftechcrunch.com%2F2018%2F01%2F13%2Fgoogle-assistant-had-a-good-ces%2F`.